# IIS cross website security with ApppoolIdentity

Tags: security, iis

I have several sites in IIS 8:
            Site1, Site2 , [...], SiteN

All sites are using the apppoolidentity.

How can I prevent the Site1 to read the files of Site2[...] by code:

```
<%=IO.File.ReadAllText("D:\websites\site2\default.aspx.vb") %>
```

If I remove in the filesystem-security for Site2 the "Users" and "IIS_IUSRS" Groups, the ReadallText code does not work anymore but if I try to access Site2 with the browser I get

```
Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory
```

Thanks for your help!
Lisa

Comment: You should set up proper user groups and DACL's. You can find information on/via [ASP.NET Partial Trust does not guarantee application isolation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698981)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I overlook your comment before but it is the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apppoolidentity does not guarantee application isolation.

You can find the solution here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2698981